# Can I configure shortcut keys in TeXworks?

Tags: texworks

In TeXworks, there is a shortcut key for the current typesetting menu, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

I was wondering if I could assign another shortcut key for another typesetting command.

For example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for `pdflatex`, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> for `bibtex`, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't the typesetting menu works: choosing BiBTeX from the menu doesn't run `bibtex` but instead associates `CTRL-T` to the `bibtex` command.  So even if you could associate a key to the BibTeX menu item, it wouldn't do what you want.

There is no way to reassign keys *within* TeXWorks itself; It also doesn't appear to be possible to assign keys through other OS-dependent methods.  For example, on a Mac, you can assign keyboard shortcuts to any menu item in any application using the System Preferences -> Keyboard panel, but this doesn't seem to work with TeXWorks. Whether such methods work in other OSes (Windows or Linux) I can't confirm.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to assign keyboard shortcuts to TeXworks on Mac OS X, because it uses non Apple libraries for doing its business. Indeed I tried: the shortcut appears next to the menu item but does nothing.

Comment: @egreg Yes, that's my experience too.  One of the downsides of cross-platform applications I guess.  So maybe any OS-dependent means of assigning keys won't work with it. (I don't have any other OSes at my disposal to check.)

Comment: @egreg I've updated my answer to reflect the facts better.

Comment: TeXworks uses Qt, so I guess that it may work on Linux boxes with KDE. Or maybe there's some utility for Qt that works also with Gnome, since each application manages its menus (which is not completely the case with Mac OS X).

Answer (score 3):

There are some pataches here which might work for you: http://code.google.com/p/texworks/issues/detail?id=17

Comment: Works for me, thanks for the hint. This now makes the editor a bit more user friendly ...